# Configure Object-Typed User Variable's Value From Package Configuration in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Here's my question: Is it possible for an Object type User Variable in SSIS to be configured using package configuration? Let's just say I intend to use the variable for storing an array, is it possible to configure it from the package configuration file?

P.S: Currently I still use string as the variable's type and then insert it into the Object-typed variable using Script Task

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to store the value of an `object` data type variable in package configuration. So, I would say that the same is true about configuring the object type variables from the package configuration. Refer the screenshot.

I am not sure what you are doing with the array type variable. However, I can suggest an alternative option that might work for you.

1. Store your values in a database table.
2. Fetch the records from the database table using `Execute SQL Task` available on the Control Flow.
3. Using `Foreach loop container`, you can loop through the result set of Execute SQL Task.
4. Within the Foreach loop container, you can use Script Task to build your object variable array or use any other task to perform your operations.

Hope that helps.

[image: Object value]